# Show that $ \inf_{c \in \mathbb{R}} \|f - c\|_{\infty} = \| f - \frac{1}{2}(\min f + \max f) \|_{\infty}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, proof-verification, numerical-methods

I'm very unsure about what I did here, so if someone could proof check on the following, I would be very thankful.

Let $I$ be a an interval of $\mathbb{R}$.

For $f \in \mathcal{C}(I)$, we say that $P \in \mathcal{P}_n$ ($P$ is a polynomial of degree $n$) is the best approximation to $f$ if $\| f- P \|_{\infty} = \inf \, \{ \|f-P\|_{\infty} : P \in \mathcal{P}_n \} $.

I want to show that the best approximation of $f \in \mathcal{C}(I)$ by a constant is $\frac{1}{2}(\inf_{x \in I} f(x) + \sup_{x \in I} f(x))$.

$\text{Proof.}$

Since $f$ is continuous and $I$ is compact, $\inf f$ and $\sup f$ are reached and we have that $\inf f < \infty$ and $\sup f < \infty$.

Hence our claim is equivalent to saying that 
$\inf \,  \{ \|f - c\|_{\infty}: c \in \mathbb{R}\} =  \| f - \frac{1}{2}(\min f + \max f) \|_{\infty}$

Note that we have that $\inf_{c \in \mathbb{R}} \|f - c \|_{\infty} \leq \|f - \frac{1}{2}(\min f + \max f) \|_{\infty}$

Thus it suffices to show that for all $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\|f-c\|_{\infty} < \| f - \frac{1}{2}(\min f + \max f) \|_{\infty} + \varepsilon$

Let $\varepsilon > 0$. Define $c =: \frac{1}{2}(\min f + \max f - \varepsilon)$. 
We have that 
$$ \|f - c\|_{\infty} = \| f - \frac{1}{2}(\min f + \max f) + \frac{1}{2}(\min f + \max f) -c\|_{\infty}  \leq$$ 
$$ \leq \| f - \frac{1}{2}(\min f + \max f)\|_{\infty} + \| \frac{1}{2}(\min f + \max f) -c \|_{\infty}= $$ 
$$ = \| f - \frac{1}{2}(\min f + \max f)\|_{\infty} + \frac{1}{2}\varepsilon <$$
$$ < \| f - \frac{1}{2}(\min f + \max f)\|_{\infty} + \varepsilon$$

Comment: Closed and bounded does not imply interval without connectedness. More importantly, from your chain of inequalities, we only get back to $\inf \|f-c\| \le \| f - ... \| $, and the other direction is still needed ( $\inf \|f-c\| \ge \| f - ... \|$)

Comment: could you give me a hint on how to show the other inequality ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint- By adding a constant to $f$, we may assume that $\min f=0$. By multiplying $f$ by a positive constant, we may assume that $\max f=1$. You correctly point out that
$ \inf_c \|f-c\| \le \|f-1/2\|.$
The goal now is to prove that $$\inf_c \|f-c\| \ge \|f-1/2\|.$$ Let $c$ be arbitrary. Note that
$\|f-c\| \ge |c|$
and $\|f-c\| \ge |1-c|$. Thus (why?)
$\|f-c\|\ge \frac12$. So we are done if we can show
$$ \|f-1/2\|=1/2.$$
Why is this true?

Comment: Thank you Calvin, I think I can justify all of the above. 

I still have the following question. Why can't I use the following theorem:

Let $S$ be a nonempty subset of the real numbers that is bounded below. The lower bound $w$ is said to be the infimum of $S$ if and only if $\forall \epsilon>0$ there exists an element $x_{\epsilon} \in S$ such that $x_{\epsilon} <w+ \epsilon$.

That's what I tried to use in my proof above.

Comment: @riri92 You can, and to apply this result, you need to check that $w$ is a lower bound; this is what I have laid out above.

Comment: So to make my proof complete, I just need to show that $||f-c|| \geq \frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: @riri92 yes, that would be enough

Comment: thank you a lot for your help !

Comment: But isn't $||f-c||$ bounded below just because for any $c$, $f-c$ is continuous and hence $||f-c|| \geq 0$?

Comment: @riri92 yes, the set is clearly bounded from below. But you need to check that $w$ is a lower bound.

Answer (score 3):

Without loss of generality, take the domain of $f$ to be $[0,1]$ and $\min_{x\in [0,1]} f(x)=0.$ Then, $||f - \frac{1}{2}(\min f + \max f) ||=\|(f-\frac{1}{2}\|f\|\|)\|.$ From the definition of the $\sup$ norm, noting that $f-\frac{1}{2}\|f\|\|$ is just a vertical translation of $f$, we have that $\|(f-\frac{1}{2}\|f\|\|)\|=\|f\|-\frac{1}{2}\|f\|\|=\frac{1}{2}\|f\|\|$. The result follows.